# Counting "repeats" in MySQL GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, group-by, statistics, repeat, web-statistics

I'm wondering if there is a way, other than sub-queries and temp tables, to count how many repeat values are in the rows you've grouped.

For example, it's easy to get a UNIQUE value count, but I want to get a count of values that appear more than once.

Example:

```
SELECT url, HOUR(dttm), COUNT(DISTINCT visitorIP) UniqueVisitors,
COUNT("visitorIPs that visited more than once") RepeatVisitors
FROM table
GROUP BY url, HOUR(dttm)
```

Any ideas?  All I can think of is sub-queries or another table.

Comment: add the structure in sqlfiddle to help you ASAP

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with a left outer join to itself, but only if you have a primary key on the table to exclude exact rows in the count otherwise a temp table would probably do fine.